# wicked_pdf renders a tiny pdf image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I have added wicked_pdf to my rails app with default options following the readme file (with the deviation being that I installed wkhtmltopdf via the osx installer).

When I render my page with the .pdf?debug=true option, the page looks exactly as it should.

Then when I leave out the debug option, it produces a PDF with a tiny version of the page. Like 1/16 of the size.

I use no options or configuration. Where am I going wrong? Where should I be looking?

Comment: what exactly is your problem? Do you need bigger font size or what?

Comment: The problem was that the page was being rendered as a 3cmx3cm mini version on the pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it by changing the `wkhtmltopdf` version from 12.4 to an earlier version.

After a lot of googling others have reported a similar bug with version 12.4 on OSX.

Maybe the answer here saves someone else a few hours of googling.

Comment: What version did you use?

Comment: I had the same problem but it was only in development (on OSX) and was fine when pushed to production on Heroku, so I just lived with it....

Comment: 12.4 has font issues, I downgraded to 0.12.3.1 and it "fixed" my all problems.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by changing the version to

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.12.3.1'
```

reference [here](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/721#issuecomment-429560752)